# Applying PHP inside multiple divs

Tags: php, html, css

well, I have been trying to implement my PHP inside multiple divs but somehow my CSS gets messed up and the records start to display diagonally i.e first record displays correctly and then the rest of the records starts displaying from the end of their previous record (that can be viewed when scrolling right). Which is very annoying. What I'm trying to achieve is: To position my divs OR PHP in such a way that my CSS does not get disturbed, is this possible? Here's my PHP code for the particular data, any help would be appreciated.

```
            <?php
                                  $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT *from `movie_schedule`");

if(mysql_num_rows($result1))
{while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
    ?>

        <div id="event" class="content-event">
            <!-- container -->
            <div class="container">
                <h3>Show Times</h3>
                                <div class="event-grids">
                    <div class="col-md-3 event-grid">
                        <div class="pic"> </div>
                        <ul>


                            <li class="hedding"><?php print($row2['Movie_ID']); ?> <?php print($row2['Movie_Name']); ?></li>
                            <li class="date"><?php print($row2['Movie_Date']); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 event-grid small-text">
                        <p><br><?php print($row2['Show_Time']); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 event-grid large-text">
                        <p class="text"><?php print($row2['Movie_Cost']); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 event-grid text-button">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="num"><?php print($row2['Movie_ID']); ?></li>
                            <li class="button yellow"><a href="#">Remove</a></li>
                            </ul><br><br>
                            <?php
            }}
            ?>
                    </div>



</div>

        </div>
```

Comment: I think you should indent this code in order to see clearly, it would help you debugging in case of some ending tags that would have been forgotten for example.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip by the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the CSS that's messing up. You're ending your loop before you close all of your elements properly inside a single block. You open the loop with a `div`, and you end it with an `ul`.
You can actually view the nested elements using a page inspector. In Chrome or Firefox, for example, this is achieved by right-clicking the page and selecting "Page inspector".

Try closing all your elements properly before closing your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up with closing `</div>`

```
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT *from `movie_schedule`");
if(mysql_num_rows($result1))
{
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_BOTH))
    {?>
        <div id="event" class="content-event">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>Show Times</h3>
                <div class="event-grids">
                    <div class="col-md-3 event-grid">
                        <div class="pic"> </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="hedding"><?php print($row2['Movie_ID']); ?> <?php print($row2['Movie_Name']); ?></li>
                            <li class="date"><?php print($row2['Movie_Date']); ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 event-grid small-text">
                        <p><br><?php print($row2['Show_Time']); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 event-grid large-text">
                        <p class="text"><?php print($row2['Movie_Cost']); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 event-grid text-button">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="num"><?php print($row2['Movie_ID']); ?></li>
                            <li class="button yellow"><a href="#">Remove</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php}}?>
```